# How to deploy java 17 application to google app engine

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-app-engine, java-17

I am trying to deploy my Java 17 spring boot application to google app engine. This works fine for Java 8, but when i deploy with java 17 i get the error: `Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 17.` This compiles and runs fine locally, and i have ensured that Java 17 is installed.

What i have done so far:

1. Install open-jdk 17:

> openjdk 17.0.3 2022-04-19 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
> 17.0.3+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

2. Update the pom.xml file and changed form 1.8 to 17

Now things build and run successfully locally, but i am not able to deploy.

I use the following command to deploy:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

this works fine before with version 1.8 (Java 8) but not with version set to 17

Full pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rest-service</name>
    <description>REST Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.44</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Error when attempting deploy:

```
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build a4a41baa-8ea6-4041-a6c9-02353d32056e status: FAILURE
.../maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.2/asm-6.2.jar
...
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  24.211 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-04T18:46:27Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project rest-service: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: `Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 17` if you are compiling on the gc there is no JDK17 availabe (or you have to configure it different) ...second the output error with `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response:` means that this plugin/service is not JDK17 compatible... and also you are using an older maven-compiler-plugin versions (I recommend using more recent versions) also your spring boot parent is using an old version of spring boot (Use spring boot 2.7.0). ..

Comment: You have to upgrade anyway and even worse you are mixing different versions of spring boot (parent: 2.4.3 vs. spring-boot-starter-security:2.5.1)

Comment: GAE documentation says it supports Java17 [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/config/appref] so it might be your configuration. Include your ```app.yaml``` file or follow the directions in the link I included

Comment: There must be a change to the `app.yaml` like this: `runtime: java17 # or another ` (coped from the docs)...